# Make rows mandatory if first cell is filled in

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an Excel file where I want people to fill in specific stuff. I want to make a range of cells in a row mandatory if the first cell in the row is filled in.
E.g. if cell A7 is filled in, cells B7-O7 need to be filled in. And this repeats itself until there is a cell in column A that's not filled in.

I tried some not very good VBA coding here

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value = "" Or Range("C7").Value = "" Or Range("D7").Value = "" Or Range("E7").Value = "" Or Range("F7").Value = "" Or Range("G7").Value = "" Or Range("H7").Value = "" Or Range("I7").Value = "" Or Range("J7").Value = "" Or Range("K7").Value = "" Or Range("L7").Value = "" Or Range("M7").Value = "" Or Range("N7").Value = "" Or Range("O7").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Alla celler i en rad måste vara ifyllda för att du skall kunna spara. Kontrollera detta och spara igen."
        Cancel = True

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value = "" Or Range("C8").Value = "" Or Range("D8").Value = "" Or Range("E8").Value = "" Or Range("F8").Value = "" Or Range("G8").Value = "" Or Range("H8").Value = "" Or Range("I8").Value = "" Or Range("J8").Value = "" Or Range("K8").Value = "" Or Range("L8").Value = "" Or Range("M8").Value = "" Or Range("N8").Value = "" Or Range("O8").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Alla celler i en rad måste vara ifyllda för att du skall kunna spara. Kontrollera detta och spara igen."
        Cancel = True

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "" Or Range("C9").Value = "" Or Range("D9").Value = "" Or Range("E9").Value = "" Or Range("F9").Value = "" Or Range("G9").Value = "" Or Range("H9").Value = "" Or Range("I9").Value = "" Or Range("J9").Value = "" Or Range("K9").Value = "" Or Range("L9").Value = "" Or Range("M9").Value = "" Or Range("N9").Value = "" Or Range("O9").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Alla celler i en rad måste vara ifyllda för att du skall kunna spara. Kontrollera detta och spara igen."
        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

It works until I get to:

```
ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "" Or Range("C9").Value = "" Or Range("D9").Value = "" Or Range("E9").Value = "" Or Range("F9").Value = "" Or Range("G9").Value = "" Or Range("H9").Value = "" Or Range("I9").Value = "" Or Range("J9").Value = "" Or Range("K9").Value = "" Or Range("L9").Value = "" Or Range("M9").Value = "" Or Range("N9").Value = "" Or Range("O9").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Alla celler i en rad måste vara ifyllda för att du skall kunna spara. Kontrollera detta och spara igen."
    Cancel = True
End If
```

Then the MsgBox pops up even though A9 is not filled in.

I know this is not the best way to achieve what I want to but it was what I came up with. Any suggestions for better code?

Comment: Just a suggestion: instead of `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "" Or Range("C9").Value = "" Or Range("D9").Value = "" Or Range("E9").Value = "" Or Range("F9").Value = "" Or Range("G9").Value = "" Or Range("H9").Value = "" Or Range("I9").Value = "" Or Range("J9").Value = "" Or Range("K9").Value = "" Or Range("L9").Value = "" Or Range("M9").Value = "" Or Range("N9").Value = "" Or Range("O9").Value = ""` you can use `Worksheetfunction.countif(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:O9"),"=")=0`

Comment: another thing: you used `Sheets("Sheet1")` only for first references, that's very risky as others might change context.

Comment: Why don't you try DATA VALIDATION is much easier !!

Comment: @RajeshS  Sorry. Dind't mention that I already use Data validation to control if the content in the cells follows some criterias. Can I have more then one data  validation in one cell?

Comment: @Stax82, since  you are  working row by row then each row needs separate Validation.

Comment: @RajeshS What would that look like. `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A8));` then what?

Comment: @Stax82, This would be better option with `Worksheet_Change`,,                                            `If Target.Column = 2 And Target <> "" Then
  If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Value = "" Then
   Target.Value = ""
      MsgBox "ENTER DATA First in Column A"
    Exit Sub
  End If
 End If `

Comment: @Stax82, this will not allow to enter data in Entire Column B unless the First cell of respective row is not filled!!

Answer (score 2):

You've got an error in your chain of conditions:

`cond1 And cond2 Or cond3 Or cond4` will always evaluate to `True` if one (or both) of `cond3` or `cond4` are `True`. This is because `And` will be evaluated before `Or`. See [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence) for more information.

You can employ parentheses to adjust the evaluation order:

```
cond1 And (cond2 Or cond3 Or cond4)
```

This expression will evaluate to `True` only if `cond1` **and** any of `cond2, cond3, cond4` are `True`.

---

In your case I'd recommend the following improvements to your code:

- Firstly, read up about loops in VBA. `For ... Next` and `Do ... Loop`
  are the two types you need to know about.
- Then, to make things a
  bit clearer (that is, let your intentions be visible in the code),
  put that *validation* code into its own subroutine/function.
- And
  finally to make it even more obvious what's happening, you can split
  up these long chains of conditions.

If we right now look at the `Workbook_BeforeSave` procedure, it's not immediately obvious what it is doing there (it might be to you, because you just put the code there and it's fresh on your mind - but come back to this sheet in 3/6/12 months and you'll first need to understand what it's doing). Let's remedy that:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = IsUserInputMissing

End Sub

Private Function IsUserInputMissing() as Boolean

    ' Validation code goes in here

End Function
```

Now everyone looking at the code can tell at a glance what will happen when the workbook is saved.

This line

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value = "" Or Range("C7").Value = "" Or Range("D7").Value = "" Or Range("E7").Value = "" Or Range("F7").Value = "" Or Range("G7").Value = "" Or Range("H7").Value = "" Or Range("I7").Value = "" Or Range("J7").Value = "" Or Range("K7").Value = "" Or Range("L7").Value = "" Or Range("M7").Value = "" Or Range("N7").Value = "" Or Range("O7").Value = "" Then
```

is not very friendly on the eyes. Verbatim it says `If FirstCellIsNotEmpty And AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty Then`. Let's code it this way.

```
Dim FirstCellIsEmpty as Boolean
FirstCellIsEmpty = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value = ""

Dim AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty as Boolean
AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:O7")) > 0

If Not FirstCellIsEmpty And AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty Then
    MsgBox "I don't know any Swedish. But please fill out the necessary cells."
End If
```

Note the use of `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank` to avoid having to type out every single cell to be checked.

---

In the end, I'll give an example of how your `IsUserInputMissing` function *could* look like. (There is still plenty of room for improvement, though.)

```
Private Function IsUserInputMissing() As Boolean

    ' Easy way to set the beginning of the range
    Const FirstRowToBeChecked As Long = 7
    ' Set a reference to the sheet that needs checking
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = FirstRowToBeChecked

    Do

        Dim FirstCellIsEmpty As Boolean
        FirstCellIsEmpty = Ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = vbNullString ' vbNullString is a clearer way of saying ""
        ' Exit loop at the first empty row
        If FirstCellIsEmpty Then Exit Do

        Dim AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty As Boolean
        AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(iRow, 2), Ws.Cells(iRow, 15))) > 0

        If AnyFollowingCellIsEmpty Then
            ' Any time the requirements are not met, notify user and abort checking and saving
            ' This is not as elegant as checking the whole range and collecting info about all missing inputs
            ' But it's way easier to code :)
            MsgBox "I don't know any Swedish. But please fill out the necessary cells. Tack!"
            IsUserInputMissing = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        ' Don't forget to increment the counter, otherwise you've got yourself an endless loop
        iRow = iRow + 1

    Loop

    ' If execution reaches this line, all rows fulfil the requirement
    ' IsUserInputMissing will have its Default value: False
End Function
```

Take your time and work through it. I've tried to make things as clear as possible. But if something just isn't clear. Don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now i will develop this code to do a little bit more.